# Calculate differences in column with column of index

Tags: r, difference

I would like to calculate differences (changes/delta) for my column `value`. Data.frame:

```
ID       Dato Tenor value   tmt
B1 2014-01-02    3M     8  0.25
B1 2014-01-02    6M    14  0.50
B1 2014-01-02    1Y    20  1.00
B1 2014-01-02    2Y    41  2.00
B1 2014-01-02    3Y    57  3.00
B1 2014-01-02    5Y    80  5.00
B1 2014-01-02    7Y    85  7.00
B1 2014-01-02   10Y    89 10.00
```

The output should be difference 6M-3M, 2Y-1Y, hence I`m looking to get at new data.frame that looks something like this:

```
ID       Dato Tenor value  tmt
B1 2014-01-02    6M     6 0.25
B1 2014-01-02    1Y     6 0.50
B1 2014-01-02    2Y    21 1.00
B1 2014-01-02    3Y    16 1.00
B1 2014-01-02    5Y    23 2.00
B1 2014-01-02    7Y     5 2.00
B1 2014-01-02   10Y     4 3.00
```

Is there a neat way of doing this in R? In general is there a way of calculating differences, where the difference is calculated wrt. a custom order/index? The indexing-variable would in this ex be `tmt`. The data.frame could just as likely look like this:

```
ID       Dato Tenor value   tmt
B1 2014-01-02    1Y    20  1.00
B1 2014-01-02    2Y    41  2.00
B1 2014-01-02    3Y    57  3.00
B1 2014-01-02    5Y    80  5.00
B1 2014-01-02    7Y    85  7.00
B1 2014-01-02   10Y    89 10.00
B1 2014-01-02    3M     8  0.25
B1 2014-01-02    6M    14  0.50
```

The result should be value(tmt2) - value(tmt1) where tmt2>tmt1 always. 
Stig

Comment: OK. So with your edit, just use `order` first and then use `diff`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is only a subset of the data. There are 2-3 more grouping variables. Optimaly I would like to order and calculate diffs per group, and then aggregate with mean. Groups consist of ID, Name, Date, and Source, leaving Tenor/tmt and value to be differenced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the "custom order/index" that you refer to, but your output can be easily obtained using `diff`:

```
> x <- cbind(mydf[-1, ], value2 = diff(mydf$value))
> x
  ID       Dato Tenor value  tmt value2
2 B1 2014-01-02    6M    14  0.5      6
3 B1 2014-01-02    1Y    20  1.0      6
4 B1 2014-01-02    2Y    41  2.0     21
5 B1 2014-01-02    3Y    57  3.0     16
6 B1 2014-01-02    5Y    80  5.0     23
7 B1 2014-01-02    7Y    85  7.0      5
8 B1 2014-01-02   10Y    89 10.0      4
```